# Find certain td values from huge table html using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

i need to write a regex for huge piece html.

```
<td width=342 align=left style='width:256pt'>&nbsp;HF Acciones Lideres - Clase G</td><td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>ARS   </td><td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Arg   </td><td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Lar   </td><td width=60 align=center style='width:45pt'>08/10/14</td><td width=88 align=right style='width:64pt'>1738.383</td><td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>51,427,906</td><td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>89,401,382</td>
```

I need to get date (08/10/14) and value (1738.383) only when the first td is HF Acciones Lideres - Clase G. I have wrote this code, but it grep some values where the first td is not HF Acciones Lideres - Clase G.

Please see (NOTE: regexr doesnt allow to save complete html so i will put here):
http://regexr.com/3alo4

**complete html**
http://fondosargentina.org.ar/scripts/cf_EstadisticaDiariaAntDetalle.asp?Fecha=08/10/14&Clasi_Id=00001

Comment: Why using regex when you can (parse and) traverse the tree-like structure?

Comment: I am not able to parse all that html using for loop.

Comment: Use a html parser or xquery

Comment: Have you checked to see if the data is available in an easier-to-parse format, such as csv?

Comment: No Andrew, that url is a html what i have not access, theres no param for access such as csv, json. I would request it as webservice and then parse using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find those values using the jQuery search methods:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $tr = $("td:contains('Lideres - Clase G')").parent();
        var date = "";
        var total = "";
        $tr.children("td").each(function(i) {
          if (i==4) date = $(this).text();
          if (i==5) total = $(this).text();
        });
        alert("date="+ date + ", total=" +total);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=728 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 8 pt; position: absolute; left: 25; table-layout:fixed; width:546">
      <tr height=17>
        <td width=342 align=left style='width:256pt'>&nbsp;1810 Renta Variable Argentina</td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>ARS   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Arg   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Lar   </td>
        <td width=60 align=center style='width:45pt'>08/10/14</td>
        <td width=88 align=right style='width:64pt'>13905.228</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>2,866,017</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>39,852,620</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=17>
        <td width=342 align=left style='width:256pt'>&nbsp;1822 Raices Valores Negociables</td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>ARS   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Arg   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Lar   </td>
        <td width=60 align=center style='width:45pt'>08/10/14</td>
        <td width=88 align=right style='width:64pt'>139941.375</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>297,644</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>41,652,710</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=17>
        <td width=342 align=left style='width:256pt'>&nbsp;AL Renta Variable - Clase A</td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>ARS   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Arg   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Lar   </td>
        <td width=60 align=center style='width:45pt'>08/10/14</td>
        <td width=88 align=right style='width:64pt'>5047.820</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>277,968</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>1,403,133</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=17>
        <td width=342 align=left style='width:256pt'>&nbsp;AL Renta Variable - Clase B</td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>ARS   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Arg   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Lar   </td>
        <td width=60 align=center style='width:45pt'>08/10/14</td>
        <td width=88 align=right style='width:64pt'>5704.307</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>3,655,663</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>20,853,021</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=17>
        <td width=342 align=left style='width:256pt'>&nbsp;AL Renta Variable II - Clase A</td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>ARS   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Arg   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Lar   </td>
        <td width=60 align=center style='width:45pt'>03/09/12</td>
        <td width=88 align=right style='width:64pt'>1604.331</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>8,658</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>13,890</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=17>
        <td width=342 align=left style='width:256pt'>HF Acciones Lideres - Clase G</td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>ARS   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Arg   </td>
        <td width=24  align=center style='width:18pt'>Lar   </td>
        <td width=60 align=center style='width:45pt'>08/10/14</td>
        <td width=88 align=right style='width:64pt'>1738.383</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>51,427,906</td>
        <td width=83 align=right style='width:62pt'>89,401,382</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Max!! it works very well, I will try to merge it using ajax request for bringing that remote html. Please note I am using google app script, and theres some restrictions :(